# How to pivot DataTable by Column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, pivot-table

I like to group a datatable by a known column but the rest of the columns are unknown. The first table in the picture is the source and the second table is the one i like to produce. Only the column that is needed to group by is sure to be there. I don't know the rest of the columns so it must be dynamic.

So far, i have tried using Linq but it doesn't product the output i wanted.

```
var dt = res.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("GroupBy"))
            .SelectMany(t => t.ToList())
            .CopyToDataTable();
```

[image]

Comment: Its not clear what your "output" table is, since it isn't really a data table.  What do you want to do with your output?

Comment: Hi @cahinton .. i think the output i want is very clear in my question as I have a picture of it. The output table will be used to create pdf.

Comment: So, for row 1 the value of `UnknownColumn1` is London?  What is the value of `UnknownColumn2` for that row?

Comment: doesn't need a value for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about pivoting a table, you are usually summarizing the data in some fashion -- counting, totaling, averaging.  If you only know one column, you can't really pivot it other than to count how many rows are in each group:

```
var dt = res
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("ColumnToGroup"))
    .Select(r => new { Key = r.Key, Count = r.Count() });
```

Gives you a pivot table that looks something like:

```
Key          Count
London       2
Manchester   2
```

To do a useful pivot, you have to know something about the data in the table.

Comment: Hi cahinton, maybe 'pivot' isn't the right word for what i want to do then. I am happy enough if the output datatable look like the second table in the picture in my post.